# When I install SQL Server 2012 Express I do not see the SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

When I install SQL Server 2012 Express I do not see the SQL Server Management Studio when I look for it via `Start -> All Programs -> SQL Server 2012 Express`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, which **version** of SQL Server 2012 Express did you install??

- there's the *bare-bones* engine - just the engine, nothing else
  (*Express (Containing **only** the database engine)*)
- there's the SQL Server 2012 Express **With Tools** version which includes and installs Management Studio
- there's the SQL Server 2012 Express **Advanced Services** version (which I believe doesn't include Management Studio)

So which one **did you** install? If you got the bare-bones one : yes, that **doesn't** include Management Studio. Either download the **With Tools** edition, or install Management Studio separately.